# multiple files upload using ftplib and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am trying to multiple files using ftp. However, Instead of uploading multiple different files, it uploads one file multiple times. What's wrong with it?

```
import fnmatch
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import ftplib

file_extensions = [ '*.mp4', '*wmv' ]
matches = []
#match = []
exclude = "/ext_hdd/download/incomplete"
def upload(file):
    ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.domain.com')
    ftp.login("username","password")
    f = open(match,'rb')
    print ("uploading" + match)
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' %match, f)
    f.close()
    ftp.quit()

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk("/ext_hdd/download"):
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
        for extension in file_extensions:
          for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, extension):
                  matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
                  (match for match in matches if file_size > 209715200)
                  #print matches
                  for match in matches:
                        pool = Pool(2)
                    pool.map(upload,match)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues. First, you're iterating over all the files in a given directory that match a certain file extension, and adding it to a list called `matches`. But then, inside that for loop, you're also iterating over `matches` and calling `Pool.map` on each item. That means if you've got two matching files, your code is basically equivalent to this:

```
for filename in ["file1.mp4", "file2.mp4"]:
    matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    for match in matches:
        pool_stuff(filename)
```

This is going to end up calling `pool_stuff` on `filename` twice, because it iterates over `matches` twice. The same thing is happening with your code

Your second issue is that you're creating a new `Pool` on every iteration of your inner loop, which is not at all what you want to be doing. You just want to create the `Pool` once, and pass all your matches to it. You also don't need to use `map`, since you're passing one task at a time to the `Pool`. Instead, you can use `apply_async` to pass tasks as you iterate/filter over the files. Here's a cleaned up example.

```
import fnmatch
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import ftplib

file_extensions = [ '*.mp4', '*wmv' ]
exclude = "/ext_hdd/download/incomplete"
def upload(match):
    ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.domain.com')
    ftp.login("username","password")
    f = open(match,'rb')
    print ("uploading" + match)
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' %match, f)
    f.close()
    ftp.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(2)
    tasks = []
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk("/ext_hdd/download"):
        for extension in file_extensions:
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, extension):
                match = os.path.join(root, filename)
                tasks.append(pool.apply_async(upload, args=(match,)))

    # Get the result of each task, just so any 
    # exceptions thrown in the workers will be raised.
    for task in tasks:
        task.get() 
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Note that I removed some code from your original example that didn't seem to actually be used for anything.

Comment: what exactly is x.get() ? Also, where should I insert ftplib section ?

Comment: It will be great if you could rework my example code instead, this could help me understand the whole picture, including where to insert file size compare section and ftp upload section. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasG.Lau I've updated the example to show the `upload` function as well. Hopefully that clarifies your second question. `x.get()` should have said `task.get()` (sorry about that) and is a call to [`AyncResult.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get). It's used to wait for the function you passed to `pool.apply_async` to finish, and return its result. I just use it so that you'll see if any error occurred in `upload`. If you left out the call to `task.get()`, they would occur silently, which can be confusing.

Comment: @ThomasG.Lau The `file_size` compare generator expression `(match for match in matches if file_size > 209715200)` didn't actually do anything since you weren't assigning it to a variable or iterating over it, and `file_size` wasn't defined anywhere, so I removed it. Do you actually want to filter out files under a certain size? Did you leave out the line where you actually calculated `file_size`?

Comment: I actually want to filter (ignore) files under certain size, I probably doing it wrong, so file_size > 209715200 wouldn't work? And if I want to do things silently after this debug is complete, which line should I comment out?

Comment: @ThomasG.Lau It would work, but where is `file_size` coming from? You can remove the `for task in tasks: task.get()` block to make exceptions in the workers silent.

Comment: maybe file_size = os.path.getsize(match) ?

Comment: @ThomasG.Lau Inside `upload`, you should be using `open(file, 'rb')`, not `open(match, 'rb')`. `file` is the name you gave the argument that `upload` takes, not `match`.

Comment: Thanks. All good. Please change your example in case someone else trying this code and ask the same question.

Comment: I found a bug which leads to upload multiple times for single file, any way to resolve it?